# List is not being populated after setting state

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, backend

I am currently working on an application that involves searching for foods from an API. I have a search bar that is sending queries, and I am getting foods back from my API calls. However, these items are not populating. Here I have some code to you a better idea of my problem:

```
void _showSearchModal(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: 0.8,
              child: Container(
                  color: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                    slivers: [
                      SliverAppBar(
                        // ... //
                      ),
                      SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate( //Here is the builder for my list
                          (context, index) {
                            return FoodTile(
                                foodItem: searchResults[index]);
                          },
                          childCount: searchResults.length,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )));
        });
  }
```

And here is the function that is sending the queries and updating the list containing the results of the search

```
List<FoodItem> searchResults = []; 

void _searchFood(String query) async {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        searchResults.clear();
      });
      return;
    }

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchedResults = await fetchFood(query);

    List<FoodItem> foodItems = [];
    for (var foodMap in fetchedResults) {
      try {
        FoodItem foodItem = FoodItem.fromJson(foodMap);
        foodItems.add(foodItem);
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error creating FoodItem from JSON: $e");
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      searchResults = foodItems;
    });
  }
```

I have tried:

1. Making `searchResults` a list of food tiles and creating those food tiles outside of the `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`
2. Printing out the length and contents of `searchResults` after setting the state and verifying its contents
3. Creating a local variable inside of the `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` and setting that equal to the `searchResults`

Answer (score 0):

this maybe because of context. that showModalBottomSheet widget is not rebuilding on SetState call.
try this

```
// create a key for your widget
GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> bottomSheetKey = GlobalKey();


// assign the key to top level widget in you builder here
void _showSearchModal(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return FractionallySizedBox(
          // in this case here
          key: bottomSheetKey,
          heightFactor: 0.8,
          ...
          );
    });
 }

void _searchFood(String query) async {
   ...
    // use this bottomSheetKey to trigger rebuild on FractionallySizedBox so it will rebuild the ui in ModalBottomSheet
    bottomSheetKey.currentState?.setState(() {
      searchResults = foodItems;
    });
   ....

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ListView.builder it may help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).